# Pre-LockScreen Application

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to develop an application that can be accessed from infront of the lock screen for either iOS or Android?

If so please provide links to relevant documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for IOS or maybe with a jailbreak but even like this I don't think so.

Comment: A solution would need to be without jailbreak to be useful.